# Related list New recorods doesnt show any fields

Tags: salesforce, page-layout

Service Resource Skill is a junction object between Skill and Service Resource which shows as a related list in the Service Resource object. When I am trying to create a new Service Resource Skill, none of the fields are showing.

[image]

Comment: Do you have CRUD permissions to the fields on this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to create service resource skill, CRUD at the parent object which was Service resource object has to be given.